# My error handler is always showing in my webpage whenever it loads

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I need a little help. When I first load my web page the input error from MainPage shows all the time in my webpage. How do I fix it so when I load the page it does show any input error?

The error should only show when a user does not input any text and clicks the 'share comment' button or if the user puts only white spaces for text and clicks the button.

Here is my code and HTML:

Code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import users

import os
import time

import jinja2
import webapp2


template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

class Author(ndb.Model):
    identity = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

class Comment(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)


class PostComments(Handler):
    def post(self):
        comment = Comment()

        if users.get_current_user():
            comment.author = Author(
                identity=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
                name=users.get_current_user().nickname(),
                email=users.get_current_user().email())

        comment.content = self.request.get('comment')
        delay = 1

        if comment.content == '':
            self.redirect('/error#comments')

        elif comment.content.isspace() == True: #checks for whitespace
            self.redirect('/error#comments')

        else:
            comment.put()

            time.sleep(delay)
            self.redirect('/#comments')


class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        query_result = 25
        comments_query = Comment.query().order(-Comment.timestamp)
        comments, cursor, more = comments_query.fetch_page(query_result)
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            user = 'Anonymous Poster'
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

        template_values = {
            'user': user,
            'comments': comments,
            'url': url,
            'url_linktext': url_linktext,
            'blank_comment_error': 'Please write a valid comment & resubmit. Thank you!',
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('page_body.html')
        self.write(template.render(template_values))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', PostComments),
    ('/error', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

A portion of my HTML:

```
<div class="title">
    <h2>User Comments</h2>
</div>
<br>
<a name="comments"></a>
<div class="comments">
<form action="/sign" method="post">
<div>
<label for="comment">Add a Comment Please!</label>
<a class="linktext" href="{{ url|safe }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>
</div>
<div class="error"><p>{{ blank_comment_error }}</p>
</div>
<div><p class="img"><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="80"></textarea></p>
</div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Share Comment">
</div>
</form>
<br>
<div class="comments">
{% for comment in comments %}
    {% if comment.author %}
    <b>{{ comment.author.email }}
        {% if user %}
            (You)
        {% endif %}
    </b> wrote on {{ comment.timestamp.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M UTC") }}:
    {% else %}
    <em>Anonymous</em> Wrote on {{ comment.timestamp.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M UTC") }}:
    {% endif %}
   <div class="comment"><blockquote>{{ comment.content }}</blockquote></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always seeing the error because `get()` is always setting it.

```
def get(self):
    ...
    template_values = {
        ...
        'blank_comment_error': 'Always seen',
        ...
    }
    ...
    self.write(template.render(template_values))
```

It looks like you're trying to signal the presence of an error by adding `#comments`, but nothing in the handler for the main/error page checks for that.

Comment: Hi Dave,  could you provide an example on how to fix it so it will show the page without error and then show the error if the user puts the wrong input?

Comment: You either need to render a template in your `PostComments`, or you could include a parameter in the query string when you redirect, e.g. `self.redirect('/?error=please+write+a+valid+comment+and+resubmit)'`. The former is more flexible but you will need to handle users resubmitting the form.

Comment: Thank you foa all your help